# SVN permissions issue on ubuntu. Going crazy

Tags: svn

I've been going over permissions for hours now, I cannot make apache to display any sub Repo. I just see svn dir with repos listed but when I click on individual repos I receive error.

Did I miss something? Are permissions correct all the way down?

[image]

Do these seem correct?

How can I make rules stricter for security reasons? And still to get repos?

Comment: And the error message is what? And in the apache error log?

Comment: @ott Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #2] definite permission issue in my books!

Comment: 500 could mean the http error code. Could you check the apache error log for more hints?

Comment: @ott that is what I get in apache logs, nothing else... on frontend http:/svn I get cannot mount svn filesystem error.

Comment: snippets from your apache.conf would help as well